# Generating a class dynamically from types that are fetched at runtime

Tags: c#, dynamic-typing

Is it possible to do the following in C# (or in any other language)?

1. I am fetching data from a database. At run time I can compute the number of columns and data types of the columns fetched.
2. Next I want to "generate" a class with these data types as fields. I also want to store all the records that I fetched in a collection.

The problem is that I want to do both step **1** and **2** at runtime

Is this possible? I am using C# currently but I can shift to something else if i need to.

Comment: Do you really need this? You can surely (A) generate a custom class as others pointed out, but you also need to  (B) know how to use it at run time. The part (B) seems like also a lot of work to me. What is wrong with keeping data inside the DataSet object or some sort of collection such as dictionary? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Make sure you have a look at the work Rob Conery did with `dynamic` in Massive: http://blog.wekeroad.com/helpy-stuff/and-i-shall-call-it-massive

Comment: Python allows for dynamic class declaration, and in fact it's common. There was a tutorial by David Mertz from around 2001 (I searched for it but couldn't find the exact link). It is straightforward.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The link you shared is dead. Do you know where can I find it?

Comment: @Joze Try here: http://rob.conery.io/2011/02/16/massive-400-lines-of-data-access-happiness/.  See also http://rob.conery.io/?s=massive

Comment: Although technically possible, I would have to question the value of doing so. The point of strong typing and classes is so that at compile time you are able to make use of the class information to check for syntax errors (newer generation of dynamic JITers can optimize without this). Clearly by trying to use dynamic typing in strongly typed environment would mean that you lose all advantages of either paradigms...

Comment: The Post from Rob Conery can be found in his GitHub repository:https://github.com/robconery/robconery.github.io/blob/master/_posts/2011-02-16-and-i-shall-call-it-massive.md

Comment: I have a sneaking suspicion that you could probably avoid the overhead of code generation and simply use a `Dictionary` or similar.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use CodeDom. Here's something to get started

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.CSharp;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.CodeDom;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string className = "BlogPost";

            var props = new Dictionary<string, Type>() {
                { "Title", typeof(string) },
                { "Text", typeof(string) },
                { "Tags", typeof(string[]) }
            };

            createType(className, props);
        }

        static void createType(string name, IDictionary<string, Type> props)
        {
            var csc = new CSharpCodeProvider(new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "CompilerVersion", "v4.0" } });
            var parameters = new CompilerParameters(new[] { "mscorlib.dll", "System.Core.dll"}, "Test.Dynamic.dll", false);
            parameters.GenerateExecutable = false;

            var compileUnit = new CodeCompileUnit();
            var ns = new CodeNamespace("Test.Dynamic");
            compileUnit.Namespaces.Add(ns);
            ns.Imports.Add(new CodeNamespaceImport("System"));

            var classType = new CodeTypeDeclaration(name);
            classType.Attributes = MemberAttributes.Public;
            ns.Types.Add(classType);

            foreach (var prop in props)
            {
                var fieldName = "_" + prop.Key;
                var field = new CodeMemberField(prop.Value, fieldName);
                classType.Members.Add(field);

                var property = new CodeMemberProperty();
                property.Attributes = MemberAttributes.Public | MemberAttributes.Final;
                property.Type = new CodeTypeReference(prop.Value);
                property.Name = prop.Key;
                property.GetStatements.Add(new CodeMethodReturnStatement(new CodeFieldReferenceExpression(new CodeThisReferenceExpression(), fieldName)));
                property.SetStatements.Add(new CodeAssignStatement(new CodeFieldReferenceExpression(new CodeThisReferenceExpression(), fieldName), new CodePropertySetValueReferenceExpression()));
                classType.Members.Add(property);
            }

            var results = csc.CompileAssemblyFromDom(parameters,compileUnit);
            results.Errors.Cast<CompilerError>().ToList().ForEach(error => Console.WriteLine(error.ErrorText));
        }
    }
}
```

It creates an assembly 'Test.Dynamic.dll' with this class in it

```
namespace Test.Dynamic
{
    public class BlogPost
    {
        private string _Title;
        private string _Text;
        private string[] _Tags;

        public string Title
        {
            get
            {
                return this._Title;
            }
            set
            {
                this._Title = value;
            }
        }
        public string Text
        {
            get
            {
                return this._Text;
            }
            set
            {
                this._Text = value;
            }
        }
        public string[] Tags
        {
            get
            {
                return this._Tags;
            }
            set
            {
                this._Tags = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

You could also use dynamic features of C#

DynamicEntity class, no need to create anything at runtime

```
public class DynamicEntity : DynamicObject
{
    private IDictionary<string, object> _values;

    public DynamicEntity(IDictionary<string, object> values)
    {
        _values = values;
    }
    public override IEnumerable<string> GetDynamicMemberNames()
    {
        return _values.Keys;
    }
    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        if (_values.ContainsKey(binder.Name))
        {
            result = _values[binder.Name];
            return true;
        }
        result = null;
        return false;
    }
}
```

And use it like this

```
var values = new Dictionary<string, object>();
values.Add("Title", "Hello World!");
values.Add("Text", "My first post");
values.Add("Tags", new[] { "hello", "world" });

var post = new DynamicEntity(values);

dynamic dynPost = post;
var text = dynPost.Text;
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can use [reflection emit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y322t50(v=vs.100).aspx) to do this. Manning have what looks to be an excellent book coming out on this: [Metaprogramming in .NET](http://www.manning.com/hazzard/).

BTW: why not just use a list containing dictionaries or similar to store each record with the field names as keys?

Comment: Thank you for the Meta-programming references.  Here's a few other I found: https://vslive.com/Blogs/News-and-Tips/2016/03/NET-Books-for-Developer-Success.aspx